# How to customize individual buttons (not the overall toolbar) in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using CKEditor in my Rails app (via the 'ckeditor' gem).
I've customized the toolbar as below. As you can see, I only want the minimum amount of features.

```
 [
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Underline' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Smiley','SpecialChar' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor' ] },
 ];
```

This works fine, but the buttons provide much more functionality than I need.

For example, the `Link` button triggers a popup that allows the user to choose details like link type and target. I want to restrict my users to exactly one kind of link. (ie. when they click the `link` button, all they need to do is enter the link, and they see no options and have no decisions to make.)

For Text Color, I just want two or three colors, instead of the 50+ that are provided.

How can I make these changes?

Would appreciate it if you could provide input, or point me to some resources.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make these changes, you'll need to rewrite the desired plugins in order to customize their funcionality.

You can find further info about it here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro

In order not to break compatibility with newer versions, I suggest you to create new plugins based in the ones you want to modify instead of doing that directly in their source code.

Comment: Thanks @Robyflc. Sounds like there's not a simple solution, but between the link you provided and other people's [examples](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all), I think I'll be able to figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Advanced Content Filter that we introduced in CKEditor 4.1. Based on content rules which you can define editor data is filtered and the same happens to UI - only "allowed" buttons and fields in dialogs are displayed. It all happens automatically, so the result may not be perfect, but we have really positive feedback about this feature.

Check [the ACF sample](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/standard/samples/datafiltering.html) and [release note](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.1-Released).

Comment: Thanks @Reinmar, this is helpful, but doesn't seem to fit my exact needs. (e.g. link tag gives me a popup with just a single blank entry field for the url, and OK/Cancel buttons, and nothing else.).

Turns out I'm already about 90% of the way there just using options like `linkShowAdvanceTab = false`, but will let you know when I get around to doing the full fix.

Comment: Yep - the integration isn't full, because the ACF is very new feature. Some things you'll need to configure manually. But it's good to start from a good set of allowed content rules, because that will configure the data filter that cleans up e.g. a pasted data.